# My nativescript app is not connecting to my json server database

Tags: json, angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am creating a nativescript app with angular, I am using a json server.
I have my json server running and when I run 'tns run android' in my  I get that it is successfully synced but my app appears blank.

I can access my json server database on my phone browser

all my cabins.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Cabin } from '../shared/cabin';
import { CabinService } from '../services/cabin.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cabins',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './cabins.component.html'
})

export class CabinsComponent  implements OnInit {
  cabins: Cabin[];

  errMess: string;

  constructor(private cabinService: CabinService,
    @Inject('BaseURL') private BaseURL) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cabinService.getCabins()
      .subscribe(cabins => this.cabins = cabins,
        errmess => this.errMess = <any>errmess);
  }

}
```

all my cabin.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Cabin } from '../shared/cabin';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { baseURL } from '../shared/baseurl';
import { ProcessHTTPMsgService } from './process-httpmsg.service';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class CabinService {

  cabins: any[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private processHTTPMsgService: ProcessHTTPMsgService) { }

  getCabins(): Observable<Cabin[]> {
    return this.http.get(baseURL + 'cabins')
                    .pipe(map(res => { return this.processHTTPMsgService.extractData(res); }),
                    catchError(error => { return this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError(error); }));
  }

  getCabin(id: number): Observable<Cabin> {
    return  this.http.get(baseURL + 'cabins/'+ id)
                    .pipe(map(res => { return this.processHTTPMsgService.extractData(res); }),
                    catchError(error => { return this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError(error); }));
  }

  getFeaturedCabin(): Observable<Cabin> {
    return this.http.get(baseURL + 'cabins?featured=true')
                    .pipe(map(res => { return this.processHTTPMsgService.extractData(res)[0]; }),
                    catchError(error => { return this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError(error); }));
  }

}
```

My app.module.ts

```
    imports: [
        NativeScriptHttpClientModule,
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
providers: [
    {provide: 'BaseURL', useValue: baseURL},
    CabinService,
    ProcessHTTPMsgService
]
```

I am getting this message in the console

× The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.
 To be able to perform Android build-related operations, set the `ANDROID_HOME` variable to point to the root of your Android SDK installation directory.

× WARNING: adb from the Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
 For Android-related operations, the NativeScript CLI will use a built-in version of adb.
To avoid possible issues with the native Android emulator, Genymotion or connected
Android devices, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK and
its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

× WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
 You will not be able to run your apps in the native emulator. To be able to run apps
in the native Android emulator, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK
and its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

× Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 28 or later.
 Run `$ sdkmanager` to manage your Android SDK versions.

× You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=28'.
 Run `$ sdkmanager` from your command-line to install required `Android Build Tools`. In case you already have them installed, make sure `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable is set correctly.

× Error executing command 'javac'. Make sure you have installed The Java Development Kit (JDK) and set JAVA_HOME environment variable.
 You will not be able to build your projects for Android.
To be able to build for Android, verify that you have installed The Java Development Kit (JDK) and configured it according to system requirements as
 described in http://docs.nativescript.org/setup/ns-cli-setup/ns-setup-win.html#system-requirements

× WARNING: The Java Development Kit (JDK) is not installed or is not configured properly.
 You will not be able to work with the Android SDK and you might not be able
to perform some Android-related operations. To ensure that you can develop and
test your apps for Android, verify that you have installed the JDK as
described in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html (for JDK 8).

Comment: Have you registered your services on app module? Is it possible for you to create a Playground sample to demonstrate this issue?

Comment: Yes I have registered all my services.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using HttpClient instead of "Http". Something like this:

AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
...
imports: [
NativeScriptHttpModule
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and then, on your service:

`constructor(httpClient: HttpClient){}`

You should also initialize your `cabins` with an empty array. Since it starts with undefined, your ListView may throw errors when trying to load data.

Comment: I did some edits like you said and updated my question because I am still getting a blank app

Comment: I am getting this message in the console:
Support for the selected Android target SDK android-undefined is not verified. Your Android app might not work as expected.

Comment: @user3149979 Can you run the tns doctor and see if path is defined correctly?

Comment: I updated my question with what I am getting in my console